# Using my developer account token for android users interacting with CloudKit web services

Tags: android, ios, icloud, cloudkit

For an android user to write to apple's CloudKit DB, the user needs to have an iCloud account. Would it be possible if in the hard code or in the web request, I insert my developer account (or my other icloud accounts)'s token so that an android user can write into the CloudKit DB without having to log on/create their own iCloud account? It's a hack but I'm curious if it's still possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having something like that in your app is never a good idea. It would be better to create a server to server token for something like this. 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW6

It would still be a hack. And it would be easy to abuse.

Comment: Thank you!! Hopefully apple allows android users to easily use it soon.